# I want to use abstract classes from C++, but why do I get a segfault?

Tags: c++

My purpose is to register the Hanlder object in the KibanaManager. When the KibanaManager obtains the log from the kibana server regularly, it will hand over the log to the Hanlder object in the queue for processing.

For example, if the Handler finds the ERROR log, it will call the showMessage function of Qt's SystemTrayIcon. A message popup appears in the lower right corner.

code show as below:

kibana.h:

```cpp
namespace favour {
    enum KIBANA_LOG_LEVEL {
        ...
    };

    struct KibanaLog {
        ...
    };

    class KEHandler {
        public:
            virtual void handler(KibanaLog *kl) {};
    };

    class KibanaManager {
        private:
            static std::vector<KEHandler *> HANDLERS;

        public:
            static void init();

            static void registerHandler(KEHandler *handler);

        private:
            static void polling(void *message);
    };
}

#endif
```

kibana.cpp:

```cpp
using namespace std;

namespace favour {
    vector<KEHandler *> KibanaManager::HANDLERS = vector<KEHandler *>();

    void KibanaManager::init() {

        pthread_t threadId;
        int code = pthread_create(&threadId, nullptr, (void *(*)(void *)) &polling, nullptr);
        if (code) {
            errno = code;
            string message = "Kibana Manager init failed.";
            message.append(strerror(errno));
            throw runtime_error(message);
        }
    }

    void KibanaManager::registerHandler(KEHandler *handler) {
        for (auto item : HANDLERS) {
            if (item == handler) return;
        }
        HANDLERS.push_back(handler);
    }

    void KibanaManager::polling(void *message) {
        while (1) {
            sleep(1);
            for (auto h : HANDLERS) {
                KibanaLog log;
                h->handler(&log);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

KibanaManagerTest.cpp:

```cpp
namespace favour {
    class DemoHandler : public KEHandler {
        public:
            void handler(KibanaLog *log) override {
                std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
            }
    };

    void KibanaManagerTest::registerHandlerTest() {
        KibanaManager::init();
        DemoHandler *handler = new DemoHandler;
        KibanaManager::registerHandler(handler);
        delete handler;
        while (1) {};
    }
}
```

The program did not run as I expected, but when calling the handler function inherited from KEHandler and overridden by DemoHandler, a bit segmentation fault occurred, which caused the program to crash.

Comment: `delete handler;` ? You do realize that you just made the pointer you pushed into the `HANDLERS` vector a dangling pointer, right?

Comment: Infinite loops without IO/atomic/volatile/etc operations like `while (1) {};` are undefined behavior and at least Clang with optimizations enabled will produce non-sense code from it.

Comment: I suspect that you believe that `delete handler;` deletes *the pointer*, but it destroys and deallocates the object it points to and that you just saved the location of. I also suspect that you have been so convinced that the problem is related to abstract classes that you didn't consider that it could be something more fundamental.

Comment: Offtopic: learn to use smart pointers ASAP. Explicit use of `new` and `delete` is discouraged for a long time (since C++11/C++14).

Comment: On another note: if you need to cast the function argument for `pthread_create`, you're doing it wrong. You *must* use a function with the appropriate prototype.

Comment: You can use `std::thread` if you are compiling using C++11.

Comment: In your example shown you probably want to avoid having a pointer to the created `DemoHandler`instance so don't use a variable at all and just call `KibanaManager::registerHandler(new DemoHandler)`

Comment: @molbdnilo Indeed, as you said, I am trying to write this program while learning object-oriented programming in C++. I am not allowed to have the habit of heap memory that has not been released, but I wrote down the delete that does not apply here.

Comment: @aszswaz `KeHandler` does not have a virtual destructor, thus is unsafe to be used polymorphically.  If you had called `delete` on `KeHandler`, and what you are pointing to is actually a derived object from `KeHandler`, the behavior would be undefined.

Comment: The access to `HANDLERS` in the two threads is also a data race and therefore undefined behavior. You need to add a mutex to guard modifying/reading it.

Comment: @aszswaz -- `static std::vector<KEHandler *> HANDLERS;` -- Multithreaded programming is much more than knowing how to start threads.  This static variable will be accessed by multiple threads, thus it has no protection against, as already mentioned, race conditions.  This is a key aspect of knowing how to write an MT program, which is why MT programming is more difficult than what you do with a single-thread program.  Learn about the synchronization primitives such as mutexes, atomic variables, condition variables, etc.

Comment: `(void *(*)(void *)) &polling` Bet the compiler complied that `polling` is a member function that cannot be passed to `pthread_create`. The cast says "No, its not. It is a free function, honest!". And then, a few lines further down, we can see that it indeed is a member function. Don't lie to the compiler, it never works!